# How to define correctly a subclass attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, subclass

I have a `Person` class and a `SubPerson` sub-class:

```
class Person:

    def setname(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def display(self):
        print(self.name)


class SubPerson(Person):
    def display(self):
        print("Name: {0}".format(self.name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = SubPerson()
    p.display()
```

But when I call the display method of `p` I have the following error:

```
File "./person.py", line 14, in display
    print("Name: {0}".format(self.name))
AttributeError: SubPerson instance has no attribute 'name'
```

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: You never call `setname`, and neither parent nor child has an `__init__` - what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: This wouldn't work even if you made `p` a Person: it has nothing to do with subclassing.

Comment: Did i answered your question correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Person:
 def __init__(self, name=""):
    self.name=name

 #def setname(self, name):
 #   self.name = name

 #instead of display
 def __str__(self):
    return self.name

 #def display(self):
 #    print(self.name)

 if __name__=='__main__':
    p=Person("YourName")
    print p
```

You have to "initialize" your attribute of your Person object.. And i would implement the **str** method to print your objects its like in C++ `std::operator<<` ..

And your subclass looks like this:

```
class SubPerson(Person):
 def __str__(self):
     return "Name: {0}".format(self.name)
```

There are some other methods(**len**,**get**, and so on..), which you can overwrite for your own Class..

Answer (score 1):

please set "name" first

```
    p.setname("your_name")
```

or if you dont want to set name, then initialize name attribute in parent class

```
    class Person:
        name = "your_name"
```

Comment: Using a class attribute is not the way to go. Use an instance attribute instead.

Answer (score 1):

> **Why?**

You should read exception message: "AttributeError: SubPerson instance has no attribute `'name'`", that clearly indicates that `SubPerson`'s instance `p` that you have created in main using expression `p = SubPerson()` don't have *attribute* `'name'` - that is why it throws `AttributeError` exception.

Lets try your code on active interpreter and see:

```
>>> class Person:
...  def setname(self, name):
...   self.name = name
...  def display(self):
...   print(self.name)
... 
>>> class SubPerson(Person):
...  def display(self):
...   print("Name: {0}".format(self.name))
... 
>>> p = SubPerson()
>>> p.name    # Notice 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: SubPerson instance has no attribute 'name'
>>>
```

Notice line `p.name` - you are getting same exception! Indeed `p` has no attribute with name `'name'` you can use introspection technique to list all attribute of `p` using `__dict__` and inherited attributes using `dir()` function, see below

```
>>> p.__dict__  
{}                 # p don't have it any it own attribute 
>>> dir(p)  # either don't inerited attribute 'name'
['__doc__', '__module__', 'display', 'setname']  
>>>
```

Notice only the attributes that `p` inherits from Person class are 'display', 'setname' but not `name`.

> **How can I fix this?**

You have few techniques to rectify your code as below:

1. Python is dynamic language you can explicitly add new name in object namespace as:

   ```
    >>> p.name = "grijesh"
    >>> p.__dict__            # Now `p` has 'name' attributes 
    {'name': 'grijesh'}
    >>> p.display()           # it is safe to call display
    Name: grijesh
   ```
2. Use your `setname` function as  @Tasawer Nawaz's answer suggestion.
3. Use `__init__` function and implement object constructor as give in @T.C.'s answer.

Basically in all technique you are attaching `'name'` attribute to SubPerson instance object before accessing it in `display()` function method.

Answer (score 0):

call the `setname` befoure your `print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly call

```
p.setname("name")
```

before accessing it